# xdsoft's datetimepicker displaying incorrect time options

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, datetimepicker

I am using xdsoft's datetimepicker plugin: http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/

I configured it using:

```
$('.eventEditDate').datetimepicker({
    format:'m/d/y @ h:m a',
    formatTime:'h:m a',
    allowTimes: ['12:00', '13:00', '15:00'],
    timepicker: true,
    lang: 'en'
});
```

However, when I click the `input` bar, I get '11:08' listed as the option three times.  The number of options corresponds to the number of elements in `allowTimes` even if I add or remove them, but the time displayed is always '11:08'.

How do I fix this?

Edit: The source code for the datetimepicker is here: http://pastie.org/9445932.  The class of the `div` with the time options is `xdsoft_today` which is used on lines 599 and 632

Comment: Can you add a little bit more of code context?

Comment: @TomásCot, I added the js library, let me know if anything else would be helpful.

Comment: Did the last solution worked?

Comment: No.  I see it works in your fiddle but not in my dev environment.  Moreover, when I use the format you used: `jQuery('#eventEditDate').datetimepicker();
$('#eventEditDate').datetimepicker(options);`, I get a list of the standard times and it ignores both the side and elements of `allowTimes`.  My intuition is that the first line initializes the datetimepicker and the options specified in the second line are not being used, but I'm still debugging.

Comment: Actually, your code is now just causing the original error (one time being iterated n times where n is the size of `allowTimes`).  This change happened when I removed the trailing `,` in the end of `dayOfWeek`.

Comment: Can you post all your code related to this in JSFiddle? Have you tried the version of the library I'm using (2.3.3)?

Comment: Using the 2.3.3 does not remove the error.  There is no other JS blocking this.  If I load no JS except the library (and jQuery 1.11.0), I still get this error.  BTW, neither of your jsFiddles are working.  I don't think the HTML itself can be causing this issue, but just in case, the pastie to the right shows the `erb` and corresponding html it generates: http://pastie.org/9451574

Comment: Hi Eric, check the updated answer, it's using your HTML. I would suggest you using the libraries linked in the Fiddle. I hope the third time's the charm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The working version is here:

```
<input class="eventStartDate newEventStart eventEditDate startTime eventEditMetaEntry" id="from_date" name="from_date" placeholder="Start date and time" readonly="readonly" type="text" value="08/03/2014 11:11 PM">

$('#from_date').datetimepicker({
    format:'m/d/y @ g:i A',
    formatTime: 'g:i A',
    allowTimes: ['12:00 PM', '13:00 PM', '15:00 PM'],
    timepicker: true,
    lang: 'en'
});
```

[See jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tomascot/w6r8twpr/1/)

Note, this required switching to the libraries linked in the jsFiddle (under External Resources). This is/was the version of the plugin: `jQuery DateTimePicker plugin v2.3.2`